# Entity Framework one to many with condition

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have a Job class

```
[Table("Jobs")]
public class Job
{
  [Key]
  [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
   [Column("fID")]
   public int ID { get; set; }

   public virtual ICollection<Note> Notes { get; set; }
}
```

The note class looks like this:

```
[Table("Note")]
public class Note
{
  [Key]
  [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
  [Column("fID")]
  public int ID{get; set;}

  [Column("fld_int_NoteTypeID")]
  public int NoteTypeID { get; set; }
}
```

Whenever I request the Notes from a job like this:

```
 var job= context.Jobs.Include(x => x.Notes).FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == jobId);
```

I would like the query to implicitly add Where `NoteTypeId == 8`.

Is it possible to somehow add this clause or do I have to explicitly add it each time?

Comment: If 8 does not exist in the database anywhere, such as an enum table you can join to, then yes you will have to include 8 in your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about workaround? Add *NotMapped* property which filters *Notes collection*:

```
[Table("Jobs")]
public class Job
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Column("fID")]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Note> Notes { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public ICollection<Note> FilteredNotes
    {
        get
        {
            return Notes.Where(m => m.NoteTypeId == 8);
        }
    }
}
```

But the problem with this design is, when you select job like `var job = context.Jobs.Include(x => x.Notes).FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == jobId);`, then you load all Notes to memory, then you can access filtered notes from memory like `job.FilteredNotes`. But when using `LazyLoading` it has advantage.

```
var job = context.Jobs.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == jobId);
var notes = job.FilteredNotes.ToList();
```

### Update

You can also try *Table-per-Hierarchy (TPH)* mappimg. You have to create one abstract class and derived classes:

```
public abstract class Note
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int NoteTypeId { get; set; }
}

public class JobNote : Note
{
}

public class OtherNote : Note
{
}
```

Then override `OnModelCreating` method:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Note>()
                .Map<JobNote>(m => m.Requires("NoteTypeId").HasValue(8))
                .Map<OtherNote>(m => m.Requires("NoteTypeId").HasValue(3)); // For example
}
```

Please note that, I do not have enough knowledge about TPH. I am just trying to show some hint. Please read further about [TPH](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph).